# How to upload files with Ajax to php script with XAMPP

Tags: php, ajax, upload, xampp

I have tried every proposed solution for last 3 hours and none worked for me. Please keep in mind that I am very new to ajax.

Here is my ajax code:

```
 var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#commercialAnimation')[0].files[0]);


$.ajax({

url : 'includes/upload.php',
   type : 'POST',
   data : formData,
   processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
   contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
   success : function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       alert(data);
   }
 });
```

Here is the piece of form (it's last form attribute which is disabled by default):

```
<label id="uploadAnimation">Upload your file:</label>
<input type="file" id="myfile" disabled>
```

And here is php class which should retrieve this file:

```
include 'db_connector.php';
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
$fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

if($fileError == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
//file uploaded
}else{
//error while uploading

  echo json_encode(array(
           'error' => true,
           'message' => $message
        ));
}
```

When I try to log messages into separate file php code seems to be working but I cannot find the file in any of xampp folders.
Additionally the `alert(data);` from ajax does not show any value.

Comment: do you see the console.log(data) output though in success callback?

Comment: I see the popup but it's empty

Comment: `$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];` and `$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];` stores correct file name and type

Comment: So... are you expecting data to be JSON when logged out in the success callback?

Comment: Thanks Adam for the suggestion! I just updated my code with `echo json_encode(array( 'error' => true,'message' => "something in return"));` and it's now displayed in the pop up but still I cannot find uploaded file.

Comment: No probs, still thinking about that one...

Comment: Answer below given by Anton F is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the file first to some folder by calling move_uploaded_file:

```
   if ($fileError == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$your_uploads_dir/$name");
    }
```

Comment: I got this errors: `<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(tmp/home-cat.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\biz\pages\includes\upload.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'D:\xampp\tmp\php54A.tmp' to 'tmp/home-cat.jpg' in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\biz\pages\includes\upload.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />` Line 15 is: `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "tmp/$name");`

Comment: Thats because 'tmp/home-cat.jpg' is not a valid directory. You need to specify a full path from drive leter to your server accessible directory. Make a folder inside your site's document root and point to it. Like D:\xampp\htdocs\biz\uploads\home-cat.jpg

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much! You're the best Anton!